# How does Eclipse deploy Web Application using Tomcat

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, web-applications, tomcat

How does Eclipse work internally with Apache (or Tomcat). Beacause it doesn't deploy our Web Application inside  "webapps" directory of Tomcat. So how does it do it??

Comment: wanted to know as well..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

By default Eclipse deploys `*.war` files inside a internal *webapps* folder called ***wtpwebapps*** which is located in the following directory:

`{Workspace_location}/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps`

This behaviour however is customizable using ***Server Locations*** option defined in server options panel accesible by double clicking the desired server from **Servers** view in Eclipse:

[image: Tomcat configuration panel in Eclipse]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You can also select the second option. Then eclipse will deploy your app under the default "wtpwebapps" folder under tomcat directory.

Click [here](https://pub.scotch.io/@ankur841/eclipse-tomcat-deployment-with-gruntgulp-build) for more details on how to enable this setting