# Eclipse refuses to recompile Java

Tags: java, eclipse, compilation

I'm running a webapp through Spring MVC whose backend is written in Java. I am working in Eclipse. I'm trying to make changes to the java code (which I did not write, but am tasked with editing).

However, none of the changes I make do anything. I tried manually compiling the project in Eclipse (Project -> Build Project) but nothing happened. I even tried taking out one of the .class files to see if it would be recompiled and it was not. The directory which should have contained that file remained empty.

I've already checked and the source and deployment paths match the places in which the .java and .class files I'm working with are located. What the heck is Eclipse doing and how can I make it compile my files?!?

Comment: Is the system time/date on your system correct? Is automatic build on (in the project menu). Have you tried "Clean"ing the project? Finally, you may check the file permissions/read only flags on the class files.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have checked all of those things.

Comment: Can you add your project's .classpath file and tell us where the sources are in this project?  Did you create this project?  Get it from someone else?  If from someone else, do you have the same plug-ins installed that they did?

Comment: Find out how Eclipse was configured in the past.  You most likely did this differently.

Comment: Now I feel really stupid...there was a Java build path error that I was ignoring (since it complained about missing a file that I know was not required). However, once I removed that from the build path properties, the error went away and it compiled...

Comment: @user1513279 oh, that's the fun thing about development, all those little things that make your project compile ... not. Maybe delete the question, it's a bit spurious to post it as an answer (classpath errors are too common...and everybody makes mistakes with it).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at 
[How does Eclipse deploy Web Application using Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9482763/how-does-eclipse-deploy-web-application-using-tomcat)

Did you remove the deployed app under:

{Workspace_location}/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps

Comment: Well the thing is, the web application does deploy, since it was compiled at some point in the past. However I can't change any of the java in the webapp, since it won't recompile. So I can go on the site, change JS and JSP and see the effects, but any changes I make in Java don't do anything

And that file is still there